# StateBased Java Game - How to tell if the mouse button is released?

Tags: java, button, mouse, lwjgl, slick2d

i'm creating a statebased game using slick 2d, and lwjgl. I currently am using if statements to check whether the mouse is inside the area of the button, and another if statement to check whether the mouse button is down (the button is just a picture g.drawImage("buttonImage.png", x,y); ). So I have a button where it changes states to the main menu from the play state, but because the mouse button is down it clicks a button on the main menu state before the user is able to release the button. So I need to check if they released the button before the if statement on the main menu is triggered.

Comment: You get better responses if you include what you've tried, rather than just asking people to give you an answer.

Comment: @Zipper I don't know any ways to go about trying to fix it. I've tried google and searching on here, but I don't really know where to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is a boolean flag that is triggered when the Mouse is down, like this:
(psuedo code)

```
if(Mouse.isButtonDown()) {
   downFlag = true;
}
```

Then after that:

```
if(!Mouse.isButtonDown() && downFlag)) {
   changeState();
}
```

Please let me know if this helped :)